# Caching that resets itself under certain circumstances: Reduce boiler plate code

Tags: python, cache

In my machine learning programs I have the typical situation where I need to perform certain operations on data, which results in the following graph:

- data --op A--> intermediate_state --op B--> final result type 1
- data --op A--> intermediate_state --op C--> final result type 2
- data --op A--> intermediate_state --op D--> final result type 3

So in order to not have to repeat operation A all the time I provide a "fit" method, which implements operation A.
Then, I implement transformation methods that implement the other operations.
However, since I usually only need some of the final results in the graph leaves, I want to calculate those on the one hand lazily, but then cache the result.

Since the operations require a parameter, I provide this one in the constructor.
I also need to pass a parametrized object with the same parametrization to different parts of the the program, where the data of operation A changes, without the parametrization changing.
That is the reason why `fit` is it's own method and not part of the constructor.
Also, because of that I cannot simply cache the results of the operations that are not A, without resetting them after invoking a new `fit`.

Here is my result in Python:

```
class MyClass:       

    def __init__(self, parameter):
        self.parameter = parameter

    # expensive machine learning fitting
    def fit(self, data) -> MyClass:
        self.intermediate_data_ = data + self.parameter + 2
        self._complex_transform1 = None
        self._complex_transform2 = None
        return self

    # expensive machine learning operation version 1
    @property
    def complex_transform1(self):
        if self._complex_transform1 is None:
            self._complex_transform1 = self.intermediate_data_ / self.parameter / 2
        return self._complex_transform1

    # expensive machine learning operation version 2
    @property
    def complex_transform2(self):
        if self._complex_transform2 is None:
            self._complex_transform2 = self.intermediate_data_ / self.parameter / 5
        return self._complex_transform2
```

The problem I have with this approach is that I am repeating quite a bit of boiler plate code.
(Note, that I have many more operations that are not A.)
Namely:

1. The variables `self._complex_transform1` and `self._complex_transform2`
2. The constructs `if self._complex_transform1 is None:` could be reduced from

   ```
        if self._complex_transform1 is None:
            self._complex_transform1 = self.intermediate_data_ / self.parameter / 2
        return self._complex_transform1
   ```

to

```
        return self.intermediate_data_ / self.parameter / 2
```

and I would save a nesting.

I was thinking of defining a container class that contains the results and is reset by fit. But I do not see how to implement this without basically introducing the same about of boilerplate code into the transform methods.

Some decorator-approach might be great, but I am not sure how to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use the code in the following. Not only should the code be very convenient, but also pretty fast after fitting. It was partly inspired by https://github.com/pydanny/cached-property, which also inspired the `@cached_property` of standard python's `functools`.

The exciting additional part (and the part that I came up with :-)) is that we do not only decorate the method that is obviously decorated, but also the methods that are given as arguments.

```
import functools
import types
from typing import Union, Iterable


class cached_resetable_property(object):

    def __init__(self, resetting_methods: Union[str, Iterable[str]]):
        self.resetting_methods = list(resetting_methods) if isinstance(resetting_methods, Iterable) else [resetting_methods]
        self.reset_methods_that_are_already_wrapped = []

    def __call__(self, function):
        self.__doc__ = getattr(function, "__doc__")
        self.function = function
        return self

    def __get__(self, obj, cls):
        
        decorated_function_name = self.function.__name__

        for reset_method_name in self.resetting_methods:
            if reset_method_name not in self.reset_methods_that_are_already_wrapped:
                self.reset_methods_that_are_already_wrapped.append(reset_method_name)
                reset_method = getattr(obj, reset_method_name)
                
                @functools.wraps(reset_method)
                def wrapper(self_wrapper, *args, **kwargs):
                    try:
                        delattr(self_wrapper, decorated_function_name)
                    except AttributeError:
                        print('Twice fit')
                    return reset_method(*args, **kwargs)  # still bound zu obj, that is why not reset_method(self_wrapper, *args, **kwargs) 
                
                setattr(obj, reset_method_name, types.MethodType(wrapper, obj))

        value = obj.__dict__[decorated_function_name] = self.function(obj)
        return value


class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, parameter):
        self.parameter = parameter

    def fit(self, data):
        print('fit')
        self.intermediate_data_ = data + self.parameter + 2
        print(self.__dict__.keys())
        return self

    @cached_resetable_property(['fit'])
    def trans1(self):
        print('trans 1 - calc')
        return self.intermediate_data_ / self.parameter / 2

    @cached_resetable_property(['fit'])
    def trans2(self):
        print('trans 2 - calc')
        return self.intermediate_data_ / self.parameter / 5


myclass = MyClass(2)
myclass.fit(10)
t1_a_f1 = myclass.trans1
t1_b_f1 = myclass.trans1
t2_a_f1 = myclass.trans2
assert t1_a_f1 == 3.5
assert t1_b_f1 == 3.5
assert t2_a_f1 == 1.4

myclass.fit(20)
t1_a_f2 = myclass.trans1
t1_b_f2 = myclass.trans1
t2_a_f2 = myclass.trans2
assert t1_a_f2 == 6
assert t1_b_f2 == 6
assert t2_a_f2 == 2.4

myclass2 = MyClass(3)
assert myclass2.parameter == 3
myclass2.fit(15)
assert myclass2.intermediate_data_ == 15 + 3 + 2
t1_a_f3 = myclass2.trans1
t1_b_f3 = myclass2.trans1
assert t1_a_f3 ==  myclass2.intermediate_data_ / 3 / 2
assert t1_b_f3 ==  myclass2.intermediate_data_ / 3 / 2

t1_c_f2 = myclass.trans1
assert t1_a_f2 == t1_c_f2
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be a job for `@functools.cached_property`. It works a lot like `@property`, except it remembers the value between calls. The value can then be cleared using `del` in the `fit` function, or elsewhere if needed.

Unfortunately, the properties can't be `del`ed until they've been set, which means we have to re-add the boiledplate in `fit` in the form of `try: del x; except AttributeError: pass`. Maybe that's an improvement since it's at least centralized, but it's still not ideal.

There are workarounds like

```
def fit(self, data):
    self.intermediate_data_ = ...

    for prop in ["complex_transform1", "complex_transform2"]:
        try:
            delattr(self, prop)
        except AttributeError:
            pass

    return self
```

Or perhaps something like

```
def fit(self, data):
    self.intermediate_data_ = ...

    for prop in self.reset_on_fit:
        delattr(self, prop)

    self.reset_on_fit = []
    return self
```

with the properties looking like

```
@cached_property
def complex_transform1(self):
    self.reset_on_fit.append("complex_transform1")
    return self.intermediate_data_ / self.parameter / 2
```

But putting that data into a hardcoded string is not very refactor-friendly. Perhaps we can define a decorator to figure that out for us?

Well, I haven't tested it very thoroughly, but I think we can:

```
from functools import cached_property, wraps

def resets_on_fit(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(self):
        self.reset_on_fit.append(fn.__name__)
        return fn(self)

    return wrapper

class MyClass:
    # ...

    def fit(self, data):
        self.intermediate_data_ = data + self.parameter + 2
        
        for prop in self.reset_on_fit:
            delattr(self, prop)
        
        self.reset_on_fit = []
        return self

    @cached_property
    @resets_on_fit
    def complex_transform1(self):
        return self.intermediate_data_ / self.parameter / 2
```

Comment: Thanks! In the meantime I also found and alternative solution. Could you review this and give me feedback? I also added a question there, because I am not even quite sure how I managed to get this working. Me turning a class member into an instance member is a mechanism I really don't get.